# How to shift divs "up" in an order after deleting hiding a div with jquery/css

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is more of a specific situation, but I have rows of divs.  Right now, if I hit "View All", The second row as pictured below, pops up.  It is in rows with four columns.

```
View All
[a] [b] [c] [d]

[e] [f] [g] [h]
```

What I would like, is if [d] is deleted, [e] should take its place, and all of the other items should move up one place, so it looks like:

```
[a] [b] [c] [e]

[f] [g] [h]
```

I have the code broken into two sections.  One section (the top row pictured above), is just the four divs/items in a row.  The second section has all the remaining rows.

I have it made in such a way that the two sections are being fed by different model data (using a foreach loop).

Is there an easy way to do this?  I can already have it so that you can delete a div, but not have another take its place and then move the others up.  Thank you.

EDIT:

```
<div class="section7 clearfix">
<div class="container">

  <section class="Con1Artists" id="show">
    <article class="topHeadingTitle">
      <article class="vieAllTitle"><a id="show2" href="#">View All</a></article>
    </article>

    <article class="MusicianCol clearfix" id="hide">
<?php $tracker=0; ?>
@foreach($latest_fan_likes as $like)

      @if($tracker==3)
      <article class="boxBg latest last" id="box-{{$like->id}}">
      @else
      <article class="boxBg latest" id="box-{{$like->id}}">
      @endif
        <div class="image-height">@if(Auth::user()->get()->id==$fan->id)<a href="#" class="remove-artist"><i id="all-{{$like->id}}" class="remove fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a>@endif<a href="/artists/{{$like->id}}" title="image"><img src="{{$like->image_path}}" width="260" height="159" alt="" title=""></a></div>
          <article class="bottomTextMusic">
              <h2><a href="/artists/{{$like->url_tag}}">{{$like->stage_name}}</a></h2>
            </article>
            <article class="tooltipCon">
              <div class="nav-area">
                <div class="navbar">
                  <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class=""> 
                       </li>
                    </ul>   
                  </div>    
                </div>  
              </div>
            </article>
        </article>

<?php $tracker++; ?>
@endforeach

<?php $offset=0; ?>
@foreach($past_fan_likes as $like)

@if($offset%4==0 && $offset > 0)

@endif
        @if($offset%4==0 && $offset > 0)
        <article class="boxBg past last" id="box-{{$like->id}}">
        @else
        <article class="boxBg past" id="box-{{$like->id}}">
        @endif
          <div class="image-height"><a href="#" class="remove-artist"><i id="all-{{$like->id}}" class="remove fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a><a href="/artists/{{$like->id}}" title="image"><img src="{{$like->image_path}}" width="260" height="159" alt="" title=""></a></div>
            <article class="bottomTextMusic">
              <h2><a href="/artists/{{$like->url_tag}}">{{$like->stage_name}}</a></h2>
            </article>
            <article class="tooltipCon">
              <div class="nav-area">
                <div class="navbar">
                  <div class="container">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class=""> 
                       </li>
                    </ul>   
                  </div>    
                </div>  
              </div>
            </article>
        </article>

<?php $offset++; ?>
@endforeach   

    </article>
  </section>
```

Comment: show us what have you tried and make a fiddle .

Comment: Basically all the elements should be nested in the same parent. Creating them in separate sections seems to be your pitfall. If A and E have different parents then you would have to delelete the entire top section before the bottom four elements would get pushed up.

Comment: I have it broken into sections so that I can have the "show more" functionality.  I want one row showing, and then the rest I want to show on a click.  See code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ScZbP/ and click the div containing "d". Would really need to see your js and css code to see why it is behaving as you like.

js

```
$('#parent div').click(function(){
   $(this).remove(); 
});
```

html

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
    <div>g</div>
    <div>h</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#parent{
    width:200px;
}

#parent div{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    background:#ddd;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

EDIT--------------

OR: Combine your articles and don't list them in separate sections. When you iterate through your list of "latest" add the "latest" class to each article like so:

Here is the fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/Td8T8/2/ and code below.

```
<article class="boxBg latest"> 
     your content
</article>
```

While iterating, on every 4th item you would need to add another class 
which I've just set as "last." Why set this class? I'll get to that on another
step below.

```
<article class="boxBg latest last"> 
    your content
</article>
```

For your "past list, add a "past" class when iterating:

```
<article class="boxBg past"> 
     your content
</article>
```

And then on every 4th item again add the "last" class.

```
<article class="boxBg past last"> 
    your content
</article>
```

For the articles with a class of "past" don't display them:

```
.past{
    display:none;
}
```

And float the child articles:

```
article.boxBg{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
}
```

To show "all" like you wanted, click your view all element and show all
of the hidden "past" items

```
$('#show2').click(function(){
    $('.past').show();
});
```

So now you need these to display in rows containing 4 items so add an 
element to separate the rows/articles after every "last" element, which 
every 4th item in the list should have:

```
$('<div class="spacer"></div>').insertAfter($('.last'));

// CSS
.spacer{
    height:10px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

Now handle the clicking of an item to remove it:

```
$('.MusicianCol .boxBg').click(function(){
    // remove item clicked
    $(this).remove(); 

    // remove all spacer elements since the list order 
    // has now changed
    $('.spacer').remove();

    // iterate through remaining articles
    $('.boxBg').each(function(){
        // if it has the "last" class then remove it
        $(this).removeClass('last');

        // now we check the index of this item and detect
        // if it's one of the "4th's"
        if (($(this).index() + 1) % 4 == 0){
            // add the "last" class to it
            $(this).addClass('last');

            // add spacer again
            $('<div class="spacer"></div>').insertAfter($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The only issue with this is I am not basing this on width.  There are two separate sections, one with 4 items in a row, and then the other section with all of the remaining items (with 4 a row always).

Comment: could we see some actual code? are you placing the items in a row in a table or with a parent div as the row? more information and code would be helpful.

Comment: Ok, I will get you the code in an EDIT, one moment.

Comment: I would combine the two MuscianCol articles. I believe it would be much easier that way. I'll try to show you some code in a bit.

Comment: and are you saying that the parent "Con1Artists" has no set width?

Comment: Alright, check my edit with the new code and new fiddle. Hopefully that is what you're looking for. You now have two different ways to do this.

Comment: I tried doing something similar to your strategy, and it seems that there are only 3 items appearing in a row in my version.  Check out the latest EDIT:

Comment: if there are only 3 items per row in your version then that tells you right there that there is a problem in your loop..

Comment: Look at the Edit, the loop should be just fine.  In fact I don't have anything that cuts it off.

Comment: can you make a fiddle, that might make it easier to debug

Comment: Well obviously there won't be four in a row if they are too wide to fit in the container. If you change the width of the container, you still have the problem of them all being on the same row. You're not utilizing any of the javascript that I suggested or the CSS, or even the "spacer" div which splits the results into rows of four columns, its no wonder your example isn't working. Use the code. Before you say its "not working" use ALL of the code. You're fiddle has none of it.

Comment: But before, without having them all in a row, this width was enough to fit the 4.  In fact it is designed as such that the divs will shrink appropriately based on screen size.

Comment: Actually, from what I see, I don't have a width set.  But with my other original sections, it had 4 to a row instead of 3.  I'm not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: you do have a width set, it clearly shows `width="260"` in the fiddle. Plus even if you don't have one set, the element will have a default width set based on its contents, so that why in the fiddle its showing three. I'm done providing help on this question.

Comment: The width is set for the individual divs, but not for the overall row/section.  I'll create a fiddle to show you what happens when you close off the "article" after the first 4.

Comment: Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2XeFs/5/

This has it closed after the first four, and then open again for the second 4.  This way it has four per row.  Otherwise, if in one section, it has 3 per row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52795/discussion-between-user1072337-and-alex)